# Catch exception at root

Tags: php, symfony

I'm learning Symfony5 and I was wondering whether it is possible to catch exceptions after route's execution.

The main idea is to get rid of some recurrent try-catch blocks of code in my routes:

```php
    public function getStudentMean(int $studentId): Response
    {
        try {
            $mean = $this->gradedStudentService->getMean($studentId);
            return new Response($mean, Response::HTTP_OK);
        } catch (AbstractApiException $e) {
            return $this->returnBadRequestResponse($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function deleteStudent(int $id): Response
    {
        try {
            $this->studentService->deleteStudent($id);
            return new Response('', Response::HTTP_NO_CONTENT);
        } catch (AbstractApiException $e) {
            return $this->returnBadRequestResponse($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Do I have to edit my `public\index.php` file to catch the exception here? Is there another cleaner method to do so?

Thanks!

Comment: In which class do you write your code? In a Controller? Which route do you use?

Comment: Short answer - yes. Long answer - it depends on a great many things how to implement this. How big/complex your project is, what you are using symfony for, what exactly you want to achieve and so on. If symfony is just an api you can have a special controller that takes care of responses and catches the exceptions. Or if you have many entities and controllers you can have an abstract controller that takes care of basic operations. Event listeners, subscribers... Best thing you can do is determine what your final goal is and read the documentation on how to achieve it.

Comment: @MartinM.: That's a really little project - a few hundred lines - designed as an API. Having a special controller that takes care of the exceptions was the key. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Symfony already have an integrated solution for that, in facts, Symfony catch every exception at root and let you manage them.

You can find information [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html).

## How to do it

First, edit `config/packages/framework.yaml` and set a controller to manage all exceptions (property `error_controller`).

```
framework:
    secret: '%env(APP_SECRET)%'
    #csrf_protection: true
    #http_method_override: true

    # Enables session support. Note that the session will ONLY be started if you read or write from it.
    # Remove or comment this section to explicitly disable session support.
    session:
        handler_id: null
        cookie_secure: auto
        cookie_samesite: lax

    #esi: true
    #fragments: true
    php_errors:
        log: true

    error_controller: App\Controller\ErrorController::showAction
```

When an exception is thrown, this controller will get as input the initial request and the thrown exception. Here is an example:

```php
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Exceptions\ExpiredLinkException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Throwable;

/**
 * Controller for exceptions
 */
class ErrorController extends AbstractCustomController
{

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @param Throwable $exception
     * @return Mixed
     * @throws Throwable
     */
    public function showAction(Request $request, Throwable $exception)
    {
        if ($exception instanceof HttpException) {
            if ($exception->getStatusCode() == Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED) {
                return new RedirectResponse($_ENV['WEBSITE_BASE_URL'] . 'login?source=' . urlencode($request->getUri()));
            }
        }
        if ($exception instanceof ExpiredLinkException) {
            return $this->render('error/expired.html.twig');
        }
        if ($_ENV["APP_ENV"] == "prod") {
            if ($exception instanceof HttpException) {
                if ($exception->getStatusCode() == Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN) {
                    return $this->render('error/403.html.twig');
                }
                if ($exception->getStatusCode() == Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND) {
                    return $this->render('error/404.html.twig');
                }
            }
            return $this->render('error/500.html.twig');
        }
        throw $exception;
    }
}
```